# Is there quick matchmaking in Shogun 2?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

I was a big fan of the Rome series, and I just recently started back on the Total War series again, by picking up FoTS with Shogun 2. I'm not interested in the campaign or anything, I just want to fight in quick skirmish matches with online players. Does Shogun 2 not support that? (I don't want to go through the lengthy Avatar setup, and I wasn't interested in the multiplayer campaigns. I'm literally just looking for some quick matches, and I wasn't seeing it from the main screen.)

I'm sure quick matches are supported somewhere, but I can't find them! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Like I mentioned, I see the avatar campaign and the custom battles, but I don't see online quick battles! Did the makers want the users to start the avatar conquest and all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, match-making only works for Avatar conquest mode.
You can still got into battle-list and join or create so called "classical" battles, but majority of players stick to Avatar mode.